# Extracting parameters from a URL

Tags: r

I'll start of by saying I have no idea on how to use gsub, and I can't make sense of the code chatgpt gave me below, the code works but its extracting the wrong parameters of the url.

example URL : "https://www.somewebsite.com/bmw/430i/2018/855648"

```
extract_info <- function(url) {
  car <- gsub(".*/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.*", "\\1", sub("^https?://[^/]+/", "", url))
  make <- gsub(".*/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.*", "\\1", sub("^https?://[^/]+/", "", url))
  model <- gsub(".*/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.*", "\\2", sub("^https?://[^/]+/", "", url))
  return(list(car = car, model = model, year = year))
}
```

The code returns the car, and model as 430i and the year as 'bmw/430i/2018/8855648'.

I tried using qdapRegex and failed to adjust it accordingly as well. Please assist me on understanding which parts of the url the regular expressions are capturing and how to adjust the code accordingly.

I'm expecting to get the Car, Model and its Year

Answer (score 1):

`stringr::str_match()` gets you a matrix with columns named by matches, you can convert the first row to a list:

```r
stringr::str_match("https://www.somewebsite.com/bmw/430i/2018/855648", 
                   "^https.*\\.com/(?<car>[^/]+)/(?<model>[^/]+)/(?<year>[^/]+).*")[1,] |> 
  as.list()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "https://www.somewebsite.com/bmw/430i/2018/855648"
#> 
#> $car
#> [1] "bmw"
#> 
#> $model
#> [1] "430i"
#> 
#> $year
#> [1] "2018"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-25 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the help, was able to implement it on a wider scale.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is always in the same type of format you can use `strsplit`:

```
x <- "https://www.somewebsite.com/bmw/430i/2018/855648"
strsplit(x, "\\/")[[1]][4:6]
[1] "bmw"  "430i" "2018"
```